# How to show 2 emojis when using the geom_emoji function (related to ggplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, emoji

This code below only plots one emoji in a plot. I am keen to find out if there is a method to have 2 and possibly more in one plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(emoGG)

#Example 1
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + geom_emoji(emoji="1f337")
```

[image]

Here is another emoji code `1f697`.

Comment: Relavant GitHub issue with a possible solution: https://github.com/dill/emoGG/issues/4

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pedestrian way of going about this.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_emoji(data = iris[iris$Species == "setosa", ], emoji = "1f337") +
  geom_emoji(data = iris[iris$Species == "virginica", ], emoji = "1f697") +
  geom_emoji(data = iris[iris$Species == "versicolor", ], emoji = "1f63b")
```

[image]