# Plot emojis/emoticons in R with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, emoticons

I'm trying to make a plot with emojis in ggplot2. What I want is to show emojis instead of labels or show like geom. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355540/how-to-show-2-emojis-when-using-the-geom-emoji-function-related-to-ggplot) in Stack is very similar to my problem, but it does not solve it either, the answer is quite manual and I need to make automatic (my real data frame has 3000 rows).

Just to clarify in this plot below I want to show emojis instead of text labels or within the bars. But seems impossible.

[image]

After trying differents solutions I'm stacked so any help would be appreciated. I read different ways to face the problem like [here](https://github.com/dill/emoGG/), [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/11/emojis-in-ggplot-graphics.html), [here](http://opiateforthemass.es/articles/emoticons-in-R/).

My last try was like this:

```
mult_format <- function() {
  function(x) emo::ji(x)
}
ggplot(foo, aes(name_emoji, n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = mult_format())
```

But it doesn't work.

My data looks like this, name_emoji cames from [emo package](https://github.com/hadley/emo), and I also can change it to byte:

```
               name_emoji     n        emoji
                    <chr> <int>        <chr>
 1            closed book     1 "\U0001f4d5"
 2          confused face     7 "\U0001f615"
 3                  dizzy     20 "\U0001f4ab"
 4 face with tears of joy     1 "\U0001f602"
 5          flexed biceps     1 "\U0001f4aa"
 6             light bulb     1 "\U0001f4a1"
```

Here to reproduce:

```
structure(list(name_emoji = c("closed book", "confused face", 
"dizzy", "face with tears of joy", "flexed biceps", "light bulb"
), n = c(1L, 7L, 20L, 1L, 1L, 1L), emoji = c("\U0001f4d5", "\U0001f615", 
"\U0001f4ab", "\U0001f602", "\U0001f4aa", "\U0001f4a1")), .Names = c("name_emoji", 
"n", "emoji"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Thanks in advance! (I'm about to hate emoticons :) )

**Edit with output following answer by J_F and sessionInfo**

```
foo$name_emoji <- as.factor(foo$name_emoji)
foo$emoji <- as.factor(foo$emoji)

ggplot(foo, aes(name_emoji, n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = foo$name_emoji, labels = foo$emoji) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

This is my session:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8/C/es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] emo_0.0.0.9000     emojifont_0.5.1   
 [3] DataCombine_0.2.21 forcats_0.2.0     
 [5] stringr_1.2.0      dplyr_0.7.4       
 [7] purrr_0.2.4        readr_1.1.1       
 [9] tidyr_0.7.2        tibble_1.3.4      
[11] ggplot2_2.2.1      tidyverse_1.2.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14        lubridate_1.7.1    
 [3] lattice_0.20-35     twitteR_1.1.9      
 [5] sysfonts_0.7.1      assertthat_0.2.0   
 [7] digest_0.6.12       psych_1.7.8        
 [9] mime_0.5            R6_2.2.2           
[11] cellranger_1.1.0    plyr_1.8.4         
[13] httr_1.3.1          rlang_0.1.4        
[15] lazyeval_0.2.1      readxl_1.0.0       
[17] rstudioapi_0.7      data.table_1.10.4-3
[19] miniUI_0.1.1        proto_1.0.0        
[21] labeling_0.3        foreign_0.8-69     
[23] bit_1.1-12          munsell_0.4.3      
[25] shiny_1.0.5         broom_0.4.3        
[27] compiler_3.4.3      httpuv_1.3.5       
[29] modelr_0.1.1        pkgconfig_2.0.1    
[31] mnormt_1.5-5        htmltools_0.3.6    
[33] crayon_1.3.4        showtextdb_2.0     
[35] grid_3.4.3          xtable_1.8-2       
[37] nlme_3.1-131        jsonlite_1.5       
[39] gtable_0.2.0        DBI_0.7            
[41] magrittr_1.5        scales_0.5.0       
[43] cli_1.0.0           stringi_1.1.6      
[45] reshape2_1.4.2      bindrcpp_0.2       
[47] xml2_1.1.1          rjson_0.2.15       
[49] tools_3.4.3         showtext_0.5       
[51] bit64_0.9-7         glue_1.2.0         
[53] hms_0.4.0           parallel_3.4.3     
[55] yaml_2.1.15         colorspace_1.3-2   
[57] rvest_0.3.2         bindr_0.1          
[59] haven_1.1.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display emojis in ggplot2 using emo package in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378661/how-to-display-emojis-in-ggplot2-using-emo-package-in-r)

Answer (score 6):

Because the solution provided seems to depend on the OS, I leave below a rough solution but leave the question open still in case someone has a solution. Thanks @J_F for the support.

```
library(emojifont)
library(ggplot2)
load.emojifont("EmojiOne.ttf")
quartz()
ggplot(foo, aes(name_emoji, n, label = emoji)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(family = "EmojiOne", size = 6, vjust = -.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = foo$name_emoji, labels = foo$emoji) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

[image]
It's needed to use `quartz`just see [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emojifont/vignettes/emojifont.html#limitation)

You can also use this:

```
library(gridSVG)
ps = grid.export("emoji.svg", addClass=T)
```

And you get ✌️:
[image]

I suppose that adjusting the emoticons to the horizontal axis could be a manual solution but for now it is enough for me of emojis. However I leave the question open in case anyone has any idea why the previous solution works on Linux but not on Window or Mac

Comment: Note that if you use emojifont in R Markdown documents you need to set the chunk option `fig.showtext = TRUE`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following:

```
foo$name_emoji <- as.factor(foo$name_emoji)
foo$emoji <- as.factor(foo$emoji)

ggplot(foo, aes(name_emoji, n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = foo$name_emoji, labels = foo$emoji) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't works for me, instead of emojis appears white squares, I edit my question with the output and with my infosession... :'(

Comment: Could you please provide more information about how you get it? I saw that plotting in RStudio could not work. But saving plot as .svg also doesn't work properly...

Comment: My posted approach was made on a Linux machine, but with Windows I also get just white squares ...

Comment: Thanks for the info! It was driving my crazy. It seems more easy to plot with using `geom_text`.