# Plot emojis in ggplot2 as label

Tags: r, ggplot2, emoji

This is my tibble with emojis. Column `name` contains emojis and text.

```
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
# name   number
# <chr>   <dbl>
#1 .    63150.
#2   1289.
#3 &     1387.
#4     5055.
```

When I try to `plot` it, it looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, number))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  coord_flip()
```

[image: PLOT]

Why the emojis don't plot correctly?

Comment: From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730589/plot-emojis-emoticons-in-r-with-ggplot), it seems to be partly based on your operating system and possibly how you save the plot. I've used the `emojifont` package, which might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display emojis in ggplot2 using emo package in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378661/how-to-display-emojis-in-ggplot2-using-emo-package-in-r)